# Using Lombok @Jacksonized throws InvalidDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, lombok, jackson-databind

I am not able to get this to work (using `@Jacksonized`)

```java
@Value
@Builder
@Jacksonized
public class Flight {
    private String id;
    private String destination;
    private int flightTime;
    private int flightDuration;

}
```

With the following setup

```java
@RestController
public class FlightController {
    @PostMapping("/flights")
    public Flight create(@RequestBody Flight flight) {
        return Flight.builder()
                .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .destination(flight.getDestination())
                .flightTime(flight.getFlightTime())
                .flightDuration(flight.getFlightDuration())
                .build();
    }
}
```

This is based on `spring-boot-2.6.2` which comes with `lombok-1.18.22`. The error I'm getting is

```
2022-01-06 01:13:01.899 DEBUG 14672 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in public com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight com.trial.lombokjackson.FlightController.create(com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight): Type definition error: [simple type, class com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]
2022-01-06 01:13:01.902 DEBUG 14672 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]
2022-01-06 01:13:01.907 ERROR 14672 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.trial.lombokjackson.Flight` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 2, column: 5]

// omitted the rest of the stack trace
```

However, if I change my pojo to

```java
@Value
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Flight.FlightBuilder.class)
public class Flight {
    private String id;
    private String destination;
    private int flightTime;
    private int flightDuration;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static class FlightBuilder { }

}
```

It works perfectly. Based on what I've researched on various sites, and docs, `@Jacksonized` is supposed to replace what I did for `@JsonDeserialize(builder = Flight.FlightBuilder.class)` and `@JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")`

Am I missing something obvious here?

Let me know if additional information is required

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? Do you also have Lombok 1.18.22 installed in your Eclipse?

Comment: With lombok1.18.20 it works fine.

Comment: I have figured out and resolved the issue, see my answer below. Thanks for prompting me to look into the IDE as a possible cause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was caused by an older version of `lombok` (1.18.12) installed with `VSCode` through [vscode-lombok-plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GabrielBB.vscode-lombok), and `@Jacksonized` was only available from `1.18.14` onwards

There are multiple issues created in the [github-repo](https://github.com/GabrielBB/vscode-lombok/issues) as well but it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

The easiest way is to

- Exit `VSCode`
- Download the latest stable version from [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/download)
- Navigate to `%userprofile%\vscode\extensions\gabrielbb.vscode-lombok-1.0.1\server`, delete the existing `lombok.jar`, copy the downloaded `lombok.jar` and place into the directory
- Start `VSCode`
- Press `F1` or `Ctrl + Shift + P` and select `Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace`
- Restart `VSCode` when prompted

It should work now